# How to exchange certain bits of the register

Tags: chisel

I want to exchange certain bits of a register variable, just like the following example.

```
val data = Reg(UInt(100.W))
val re_order1 = Wire(UInt(log2Ceil(100).W))
val re_order2 = Wire(UInt(log2Ceil(100).W))
//Exchange the bits of the data register in re_order1 and re_order2
data(re_order1) := data(re_order2)
data(re_order2) := data(re_order1)
```

I tried to use shift and mask to achieve, but found it will be very complicated, is there a simple way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following chisel `Module` does what I think you are aiming for here, that is: flip two arbitrary dynamically indexed bits in a register. This is going to require a lot of `Mux`es to accomplish this but I think this example shows that chisel can generate those pretty cleanly. The basic strategy is to treat the register as a `Vec` of bools then create a `Mux` every one of those bools to any other bit, based on whether the bit is referenced as one of the two bit addresses.
Then convert the sequences of generated as a new `Vec` using `VecInit` and then convert that `vec` to a `UInt` and wire it back into `reg`.

This module has a little bit of additional code to load the register. You may want to do that some other way.

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util.log2Ceil
import chiseltest._
import org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class FlipBits(bitWidth: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val load = Input(Bool())
    val loadValue = Input(UInt(bitWidth.W))
    val bitAddress1 = Input(UInt(log2Ceil(bitWidth).W))
    val bitAddress2 = Input(UInt(log2Ceil(bitWidth).W))
    val out = Output(UInt(bitWidth.W))
  })

  val reg = RegInit(0.U(bitWidth.W))
  val bits = VecInit(reg.asBools())

  when(io.load) {
    reg := io.loadValue
  }.otherwise {
    reg := VecInit(bits.indices.map { index =>
      val index1 = Mux(index.U === io.bitAddress1, io.bitAddress2, index.U)
      val index2 = Mux(index.U === io.bitAddress2, io.bitAddress1, index1)
      bits(index2)
    }).asUInt
  }

  io.out := reg
}
```